# is there a setting to deny an ARP request from another subnet

Tags: subnet, arp

## Network Setup

```
|HOST_A| 10.32.204.X/24 |ROUTER| 10.163.10.X/240 |HOST_B| Loopback: 10.163.10.246/32
      .2<------------->.1    .55<--------------->.75
```

## Problem

I have a setup similar to the one above where I want to reach a HOST_B via a looback IP that is routed in my network.

In normal conditions I can reach 10.163.10.246 from my host 10.32.204.2.

However, we noticed in a production network that the comms can fail.
We narrowed it down to a problem with ARP.

If HOST_B does not have an ARP entry for ROUTER's IP 10.163.10.75 (e.g. it timed out) it sends out an ARP request.
However, instead of using its line interface IP address 10.163.10.75 it puts its Loopback IP 10.163.10.246 as sender IP address (probably because that is the IP it tried to reach)

The HOST_B Loopback and the ROUTER interface IP belong to two different IP subnets.

The Cisco router in my test lab answers this ARP request and IP comms between HOST_A and HOST_B will come up.
However, in the production network ROUTER will not answer to the ARP request, therefore IP comms will fail.

## Question(s)

- Should ROUTER have to answer the ARP request even if the sender IP address is outside of its IP range?
- Is there a known setting to deny such a ARP request?
- Is there any documented best practices?

I had a look at the ARP RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) but it seems not to be specific to resolving IP, so it does not define if a check against subnets should be made.

Comment: It sounds like something upstream, perhaps your cisco router, has proxy arp enabled and the subnet mask of an interface is incorrect?

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your feedback. I don't think it is a wrong interface config since this happens in several places in the network (the setup above is present in multiple locations). This seems to be systematic. My suspicion is that the ops team enabled some sort of security setting. I don't think it is proxy arp however.